# Is there a way to delete rows from a csv file based on a list values from another file in windows?

Tags: windows, csv, delete-row

I have two files:

candidates.csv:

```
id,value
aman,123
raju,1
suzy,5
```

blacklist.csv:

```
aman
suzy
```

resulting csv must be:

```
raju,1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added field name in blacklist.csv:

```
id
aman
suzy
```

Then you can use [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/) and run

```
mlr --csv join --np --ul -j id -f candidates.csv then unsparsify blacklist.csv >output.csv
```

to have

```
id,value
raju,1
```

It's a left [join](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-verbs/index.html#join) (`--ul`) that does not emit paired records (`--np`)